# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null JsonWriter.writeDeferredName but not using Json?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, stack-overflow, overflowexception

I know the title isn't the best, but the error is not clear at all to me. The error I have is this:

```
019-04-15 14:28:45.270 ERROR 12644 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:480) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3.write(TypeAdapters.java:148) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3.write(TypeAdapters.java:133) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at 

[...]
```

The `[...]` is because these lines repeat for a crazy amount of time and they're all the same. For what I understood by searching the error, it should be some problem with recursivity and infinite loop, but in my code I don't get where this is.
This is the method I'm calling:

```
@PostMapping(path=PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody(required=false) Map<String,Object> params) throws FileNotFoundException {

        LOGGER.info("starting process definition with id {}", processDefinitionId);

        ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> response = null;

        ProcessInstance pi = null;
        LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
        try {
            if(params!=null) {
                pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId, params);
                List<org.flowable.task.api.Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().list();
                System.out.println("Length " + tasks.get((tasks.size()-1)).getProcessVariables());
                org.flowable.task.api.Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(pi.getId()).singleResult();
                if(task==null) {
                    System.out.println("Task is null");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Info task " + runtimeService.getVariables(pi.getId()));
                }

            }  else {
                System.out.println("Empty ");
                pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId);
            }


            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(Constants.OK, pi), HttpStatus.OK);

            MongoOperations.writeLogSuccess(pi ,pi.getProcessDefinitionName(), "OK"); //if it went well
        } catch (FlowableObjectNotFoundException e) {
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogFailure(time, pdn, "KO not found");
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        catch (FlowableException e) { //TEST EXCEPTION WITH FAILSTATUSCODE
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogFailure(time, pdn, "KO flowable");
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); //other exception are managed here
        } catch(Exception e) {
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogFailure(time, pdn, "KO general");
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); //other exception are managed here
        }



        return response;
    }
```

I really don't understand what's causing this and why. The `params` I'm passing through post request is a Json string written in this way:

```
{
    "input":2
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Which point in the above code throws the exception? Is it when you convert the response to JSON or when you deserialize your input to POJO? Can you try a standalone code which does the serializing/deserializing and try to recreate the error?

Comment: Hi @sinujohn I'm not performing deserializing operations with JSON

Comment: You are serializing some value into JSON. What is the value that you are trying to write? Which line in the above code throws the exception?

Comment: @sinujohn in the code I posted and that I'm calling I'm not performing "explicit" serialization, and no other point in the code where I'm doing that. I suspect it could be an "implicit" serialization performed by the POST endpoint when retrieving RequestBody? Otherwise I don't know what else it could be. In this case what can I do?