# StackOverflowError: null at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value

Tags: json, http-post, catalina, catalina.out, flowable

Referring to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689432/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-jsonwriter-writedeferredname-but-not-using-js), it seems I have a problem with the whole method that I do not understand. In fact, right now I do not have the error specified in the question anymore, but I have a new one:

```
2019-04-16 16:32:16.843 ERROR 7452 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.nio.CharBuffer.<init>(CharBuffer.java:281) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:393) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:280) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:566) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:406) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:390) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
[...]
```

In the whole stack trace I have these lines repeating and no info about the line throwing this error. I'm working with flowable and passing data through POST request. The method I'm using is this:

```
@PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId,
            @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params) throws FileNotFoundException {

        LOGGER.info("starting process definition with id {}", processDefinitionId);

        Map<String, Object> variables;
        ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> response = null;
        PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
        System.setOut(o);
        ProcessInstance pi = null;
        LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
        try {
            if (params != null) {           
                pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId, params);          
            } else {
                System.out.println("Empty ");
                pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId);
            }

            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(Constants.OK, pi), HttpStatus.OK);

            if(pi.isEnded()) {      
                HistoricProcessInstance hpi = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().includeProcessVariables().
                        processInstanceId(pi.getId()).singleResult();
                variables = hpi.getProcessVariables();
                System.out.println("Variables " + variables);
                if(variables.get("result").equals("OK")) {
                    MongoOperations.writeLogSuccess(pi, pi.getProcessDefinitionName());
                } else {
                    MongoOperations.writeLogFailure(hpi.getDurationInMillis(), hpi.getStartTime(), pi.getProcessDefinitionName());
                }
            }
            else {
                variables =  runtimeService.getVariables(pi.getId());
            }
        } catch (FlowableObjectNotFoundException e) {
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogException(time, pdn);
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (FlowableException e) { 
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogException(time, pdn);
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // other exception are managed here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String pdn = repositoryService.getProcessDefinition(processDefinitionId).getName();
            MongoOperations.writeLogException(time, pdn);
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(e.getMessage(), null), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // other exception are managed here
        }

        return response;
    }
```

The method's logic itself is correct, I'm able to do all my operations correctly. This error happens both when Exceptions are thrown or not thrown. Where I can start to check the error?
From the stack trace it appears to be a `JsonWriter` error, and the only "Json operation" that is done is probably when retrieving the `params` from the request body, but knowing that how can I fix it? I can't even understand the reason behind this error...

**EDIT**

So I'm understanding that the possible cause for this error is that Gson does not work well with Object. Is it right? In this case, how can I fix this since my method takes only a `Map<String,Object>` ?

**EDIT 2**

Ok so, I've found a workaround but I don't like it, but for now is all I have, and is this:

```
@PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId,
            @RequestBody(required = false) Map<?,?> params) throws FileNotFoundException {

        LOGGER.info("starting process definition with id {}", processDefinitionId);

        Map<String, Object> variables = (Map<String, Object>) params;
```

And then I pass variables to my method. Anyway, a (slightly) new error is thrown:

```
2019-04-16 17:08:02.638 ERROR 9524 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.isCommitted(Response.java:255) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:599) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:657) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:368) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:303) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:591) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:406) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:390) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have those exception is most probably the fact that you are trying to serialize the `ProcessInstance`. I would highly advise against doing that and creation your own representation that would contain only the information you need.

Gson and Jackson use reflection to perform the serialization. Although the `ProcessInstance` interface has simple getters, the implementation is much more nuanced and can has a cyclic reference to itself (which is the reason why you re seeing the stackoverflow).

Comment: Hi, I'm not serializing the ProcessInstance, inside the MongoOperation I'm calling I save a custom document with informations retrieved from the ProcessInstance, but not the process instance itself

Comment: I am talking about the return of your method. You are returning `ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>>` and the returned response is `response = new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse<>(Constants.OK, pi), HttpStatus.OK);`. Where `pi` is the Flowable `ProcessInstance`